# Visibility based on flag in another model - Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to add a read only condition based on boolean fields in another model in this example the flags are being set in the model "sale_order" and the fields  want to make read only are in the "sale_order_line" i think its a matter of context but can't seem to make it work.

I've tried something like this but context might be off.

```
<field name="trave_weeks" attrs="{'readonly':['&amp;',('expend_percetage', '=', False),('fixed_expend', '=', False)]}"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parent fields through `parent.field_name`.

```xml
<field name="trave_weeks" attrs="{'readonly':['&amp;',('parent.expend_percetage', '=', False),('parent.fixed_expend', '=', False)]}"/>
```